# What is it called when you set properties on object initialization?

Tags: c#, naming

What is it called when you set properties on object initialization?

```
var customer = new Customer() {RequestID = request.ID, AddressID = 5};
```

Is it considered good practice?

Comment: It's just a convenient syntax, but notice how well your example reads.  By the way, you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: @Robert Harvey your right. Neat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) or object initialization expressions, in C# at least.  Its implementation was necessary for LinQ, to dynamically create anonymous types in a convenient manner.

Whether it's a good practice or not depends on how you use it. Read Jon Skeet's [thoughts about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067914/c-object-initializer-complexity-best-practice) them on stackoverflow to gain some more insight. Jimmy Hoffa also wrote an [excellent answer on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4325/styles-object-initializer-vs-constructor-object-creation). He proposes to base the decision for or against object initializers on the question:

*Is the object safely usable if the properties are null?*

If so, then object initializers provide a very convenient and readable way to create an object.

Comment: The object cant be used if they are null. However as its a datacontract it has to be mutable anyway.

Comment: @Tom Squires: How many properties have you got? If it's a significant amount (more than 5 for my personal taste) don't enforce their initialization via a constructor, as it'd just be a pain to use and maintain these constructors. I've had these cases in which the constructor took 10 arguments and the compiler kept complaining because I didn't meet the signature (and couldn't see why for 10 minutes) or the constructor lacked validations anyway, which made the whole intent rather pointless.

Comment: @Tom Squires: Just set them via an initializer or traditionally and add a Unit test or put the validation elsewhere, for example in the object which processes the data and have that object throw an exception. In many cases that is just as good.

Comment: @Tom Squires: Another factor that just came to my mind is: Does the object need these values to maintain its own integrity or is this integrity only important to something external. If the integrity is only important to something external, then have the validation there. In the end, the most important thing are meaningful error messages, so you can trace the fault quickly.

Answer (score 10):

To add a bit to Falcon's good answer:

> What is the name for setting properties when an object is instantiated?

It is an "object initializer". Note that the equivalent feature for collections is called a "collection initializer". That is, you can also say

```
x = new List<int>() { 10, 30, 20 };
```

and that will be translated into

```
var temp = new List<int>();
temp.Add(10);
temp.Add(30);
temp.Add(20);
x = temp;
```

for you. You can even mix object and collection initializers! See the C# specification section 7.6.10.3 for an example of how to use a collection initializer inside an object initializer.

> Is it considered good practice?

We didn't add it to C# 3.0 because it was a bad practice!

The compelling benefit of object and collection initializers is not just that they are a much more compact, less "ceremonial" way to create and initialize an object. The compelling benefit is also that *an object initializer is an expression, not a collection of statements*. That means that you can use them in contexts where expressions are legal but statements are not, like:

- field and local initializers
- array initializers
- expression lambdas
- LINQ query comprehensions
- and so on

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's good practice.  It's more readable because you don't have the repetition of `customer.` and `=`.   It may seem like a minor point, but it takes time and energy to scan those lines and verify that indeed they are all initializing `customer`.

And consider this:

```
var customer1 Customer();
customer1.RequestId = request.id1;
customer1.AddressId = 3;
customer1.Name = 'Nick Nicely'

var customer2 = new Customer();
customer2.RequestId = request.id2;
customer2.AddressId = 5;
customer1.Name = 'Poor Nick!'
```

Repetitive code is prone to cut-and-paste errors.  It's much better to express a simple thought (Create a new customer) in a single sentence (line of code) whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it considered good practice?

I would suggest that it's not "bad" practice, being that it's mainly just a convenience feature.  There is no difference between

```
var customer = new Customer() {RequestID=request.ID, AddressID = 5 };
```

or

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.RequestId = request.ID;
customer.AddressID = 5;
```

Other than ceremony.

Comment: Well that is simply not true. There is a difference - using object initializer won't allow you to set the same property twice. And it's not purely theoretical; it can prevent bugs. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice bit of syntactic sugar and isn't really "good" or "bad" practice so much as it is a matter of style. The approach you should always go for is what improved readability.

Generally I will use this form whenever assignments are straightforward, whenever an assignment becomes more than giving in a value or a possibly a value and a quick trim() I will take it out and assign it to the object explicitly.

I also find it's helpful when I have to make a larger number of assignments and do it like:

```
var customer = new Customer(){
    RequestID = request.ID,
    AddressID = 5,
    Firstname = "Bob",
    Lastname = "Jones",
    FavouriteColor = "Blue",
    someOtherProperty = "Maybe"
}
```

I find the indentation and codeblock brackets just help make it more explicit and easier to skim through your code.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of these initializers that noone has mentioned is that they prevent silly mistakes:

```
FileTransfer transfer = new FileTransfer();
transfer.ID = request.ID;
transfer.SourcePath = request.DownloadLink;
transfer.FileName = FileNameFromLink(request.DownloadLink);
transfer.SourcePath = request.Destination;
```

This will compile, and be buggy.

```
FileTransfer transfer = new FileTransfer
{
    ID = request.ID,
    SourcePath = request.DownloadLink,
    FileName = FileNameFromLink(request.DownloadLink),
    SourcePath = request.Destination
};
```

Now this will *not*, and so it'll help you spot that `SourcePath` is being set twice by mistake (instead of `TargetPath`)

Answer (score 0):

It's new with VS2008. If you need to write portable code that also compiles under VS2005 and earlier mono, refrain from using it.

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of using Object Initializer syntax with anything other than simple values.

If you start having complex calls as part of the value initialisations it can be very hard to debug as an error in one of the value calls can be reported in the Constructor call and it's much harder to workout which value is actually causing the problem.